# Prove that: $2^n < n!$ Using Induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm told to show that $2^n < n!$ using induction

This is my attempt at it:

BC: $n=4, 2^4 = 16 < 4!$

IH: n = k, $2^k < k!$

IS: try n = k+1

I'm told to only work from one side, so I try the left side:

2^(k+1)

But I'm stuck here, any ideas?

Comment: the base case seems to have failed. $2^1 = 2 > 1 = 1!$.

Comment: $2^{k+1} = 2 \times 2^k < 2 \times k!$. Your base case should be $4$ though.

Comment: I've fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true only for $n\ge 4$.

**Hint for the inductive step:**

$2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^k<2\cdot k!$, so it is enough to prove $2\cdot k!\le (k+1)!$.

Comment: Could you expand on that, I'm not sure how to follow from there?

Comment: If  $2\cdot k!\le (k+1)!$ and $2^{k+1}<2\cdot 2^k$, the inductive step will follow by transitivity. Now $2\cdot k!\le (k+1)!=(k+1) \,k! \iff 2\le k+1$, i.e. $\;k\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $2^k<k!$ by induction hypotheses. Then $2^k(k+1)<(k+1)k!=(k+1)!$,  if $k>3$ you have that $2^{k+1}<(k+1)2^k$ and the result follows.

Comment: $1 \lt k \implies 2 \lt k+1$. So $2^{k+1} = 2^k \times 2 < k! * (k+1) = (k+1)!$

Comment: By hypothesis $k>3$. It is just a redundant argument, I know. Otherwise you can not use induction.

Comment: If k>3, then is it true that k>1? Hence is it true that 2 < k+1?

Answer (score 1):

This is true for $n \geq 4$.

Base step: $2^4 < 4!$ i.e. $16 < 24$ true!

Induction Step: suppose $2^{n-1} < (n-1)!$. Since $2<n$ you can multilpy the left side for $2$ and the right side for $n$ keeping the inequality true, so you get

$2 \cdot 2^{n-1} < n(n-1)!$ i.e. $2^n < n!$.